# Vhdl Multiplier usage too low

Tags: fft, vhdl, ram, multiplication, mux

My design utilizes the Spartan 3E XC35100E device. I can use a total of 4 MUX. However, despite using 3 * signs and a FFT block (which also uses 3 MUX), the design summary specifies that I only use 1 MUX. Even when I use CLB logic in place of MUX for the FFT block, the design summary is the same.

Implementation and simulation are able to take place without any problems. So, why is the number of MUX I use so low? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

relevant libraries, port maps and signal declarations are excluded for brevity.

```
process (clk) 
 variable fsm : integer range 0 to 3:= 0;
 variable i : integer range 0 to 127:= 0; 
begin

if rising_edge(clk) then
    if fsm = 0 then
        tasiyici <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_signed(sample_1(i)* sample_2(i) , 16));
 --sample1 and sample 2 are arrays with constant values
        fsm := fsm +1;


    elsif fsm = 1 then
        wea_select <= '0';
        wea_ram<= "1";
        ram_write <= '0';
        dina <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(tasiyici(15 downto 8));
        mult_out<= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(tasiyici(15 downto 8));
        fsm := fsm +1;

    elsif fsm = 2 then
        address_write <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(addra) + 1);
        wea_ram<= "0";
        i := i+1 ;
        if i=128 then
            fsm:=3;
            ram_write <= '1';
            wea_select <= '1';
        else
            fsm := 0;
        end if;

    end if;

end if;

end process;


----FFT process---
process(clk) 
variable fsm : integer range 0 to 7:= 0;
variable i : integer range 0 to 128; 
variable counter : integer range 0 to 2:= 0;
variable j : integer range 0 to 512; 

begin
if rising_edge(clk)  then

    if fsm = 0 then  -- ram_write is control 
        if ram_write = '1' then 
            wea_fft <= "0";
            fsm:= 1;
        end if;

    elsif fsm = 1 then --process start (pulse)
        start <= '1';
        fwd_inv_we <= '1';
        fsm := fsm +1;

    elsif fsm = 2 then
            start <= '0';
            fwd_inv_we <= '0';
            fsm := fsm +1;

    elsif fsm =3 then --128 cycle send data from douta to xn_re
        if i= 128 then
            fsm := fsm +1;
        else
            xn_re <= douta;
            address_read <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(addra) + 1);
            i:=i+1;
            fsm := 3;
        end if;

     elsif fsm =4 then --all data sent. process complete
        if done = '1'  then --wait for done finish 3 clk cycle, then unload
            if counter= 2 then
                fsm := fsm +1;
            else
                counter := counter +1;
                fsm :=4;
            end if;
        end if;

    elsif fsm =5 then
        counter := 0;
        unload <= '1';
        fsm := fsm +1;
        fft_data_ready <= "1";      
        wea_fft<= "1";


    elsif fsm =6 then --wait 512 clk cycle to read all outputs
        unload <= '0';
        wea_fft<= "0";

        if dv = '1' then

  fft_output <=  std_logic_vector(signed(xk_re(15 downto 4))*signed(xk_re(15 downto 4))
                               +signed(xk_im(15 downto 4))*signed(xk_im(15 downto 4)));             
            if j=512 then 
                fsm:=fsm+1;
            else
            j:=j+1;
            fsm:=6;
            end if;
        else
            fsm:=6;
        end if;
    end if;
end if;
end process;
```

Comment: MUX is generally a term used to describe a <b>MU</b>ltiple<b>X</b>er. constant values will be optimized away during synthesis (e.g. `sample_1(i)`, `sample_2(i)`). The remaining  two multiply operators present in your unlabelled FFT process have operands (`xk_imm`, `xk_re`) for which neither declarations nor assignment are visible. If the operands are provided successively a single multiplier may be adequate. This is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I tried keeping all signal assignments and declarations in order to make the code shorter. Everything you say makes sense, but the lack of multipliers occurs despite using a FFT IP core which claims to use 3 MUX. Is there some other problem that I'm not noticing here? 
I'll make more of an effort to get the formatting right!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting the results of a VHDL specification that simulates, and who's implementation works. It's not a programming question and might be better asked on electronics.stack.exchange. Nor can it be reproduced, lacking an MVCe.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your design has simply been optimized.

You should check the RTL that is synthesized to check that your design has been synthesized the way that you wanted